# cannot handle exceptions in spring batch integration flow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to set up a flow that handle exceptions thrown during batch execution (this job is executed through the flow startBatchFlow), but the program ends without copying the files to the error directory.

Could you suggest a solution to handle the errors thrown during the execution of the flow?

Here is my code :

```java
 @Value("${app.file.error}")
 private String errorPath;

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("errorChannel")
 private PublishSubscribeChannel errorChannel;

 @Bean
 public IntegrationFlow startBatchFlow(@Qualifier("fileReaderChannel") MessageChannel fileReaderChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(fileReadingMessageSource(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period))) //
        .channel(fileReaderChannel)
        .handle(fileWritingMessageHandler())
        .aggregate(agg -> agg.correlationExpression("payload != null")
            .releaseStrategy(new ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy("size == 2"))
            .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
        )
        .transform(fileMessageToJobRequest()) //
        .handle(jobLaunchingMessageHandler()) //
        .wireTap(sf -> {
            sf.handle(jobExecution ->
                log.info("job Execution payload " + jobExecution.getPayload()));
        })
        .split(messageSplitter)
        .wireTap(sf -> {
            sf.handle(jobExecution ->
                log.info("Message after split payload =" + jobExecution.getPayload())); // to modify
        })
        .route(Message.class, message -> message.getPayload() != null,
            mapping -> mapping.subFlowMapping(true, archiveFilesFlow())
        )
        .get();
 }

 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel)
                .handle(message -> System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + message.getPayload()))
                .get();
    }
```

this the stack trace:

```
 Encountered an error executing step businessDataExcelFileStep in job generateOpcvmJob

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to invoke method: [public void fr.project.sample.steps.DataItemReader.beforeStep(org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution)] on object: [fr.project.sample.steps.BusinessDataItemReader@79d743e6] with arguments: [[StepExecution: id=1, version=1, name=businessDataExcelFileStep, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=]]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.SimpleMethodInvoker.invokeMethod(SimpleMethodInvoker.java:112) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.MethodInvokerMethodInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvokerMethodInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy57.beforeStep(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    
    
2022-05-11 15:40:01.123  WARN 19196 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher  : Suppressing Exception since 'ignoreFailures' is set to TRUE.

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: failed to write Message payload to file in the [bean 'fileWritingMessageError' for component 'errorHandlerFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [fr/project/sample/config/FilesReaderIntegrationConfig.class]'; from source: 'fr.project.sample.config.FilesReaderIntegrationConfig.fileWritingMessageError()']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Message payload type [org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:543) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:222) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.8.jar:5.5.8]
```

**Edit my code :**

```
 Message errorMessage=   MessageBuilder.withPayload(new ErrorMessage(new BusinessException("Business File not exist"))).build();
          errorChannel.send(errorMessage);
```

after this modification (sending exception  at the step '.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest()))  ), i
I get the message on the errorChannel. But the problem is that it launches the other steps of the flow or that it should stop and not go to the next steps handle(jobLaunchingMessageHandler( )).

Comment: May we see some stack traces related to the errors you are mentioning?

Comment: `agg.correlationExpression("payload != null")`. Payload of the message is never `null`. On the other hand it is not clear what is the purpose of always `true` correlation key. Please, learn more what is that: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator

Comment: I am running a job that may generate exceptions during processing. 
I want to not terminate the flow execution in case of exception and move the message to errorChannel . app should not execute the part : .route(Message.class, message -> message.getPayload() != null,
                        mapping -> mapping.subFlowMapping(true, archiveFilesFlow())
                )
because an exception was generated when the job was launched.

Comment: What is an exception thrown? How does it look i n your logs? The poller in the beginning of your flow really relies on the `errorChannel` by default. It might be the fact that your batch job shifts its work to another thread and exception is not propagated back to your flow. So, it is indeed not terminated although it does not handle errors as you’d expect. I’m not sure in your last sentence. As I said before: that check does not make sense since it is always true. Consider to not use router: plain handle or channel should be enough to end the flow

Comment: Please, edit your question and add a stack trace over there (or log). I guess your exception is thrown anyway, but it just does not reach an `errorChannel`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I changed the .route with a plain handle. Also, I added a stack trace in the question

Comment: So, it  looks like your exception reaches an error handler, but only the problem that `FileWritingMessageHandler` does not support the `MessageHandlingException` as payload to be able to write it into the file. You may need to implement some logic upfront to transform that exception to supported file content. The `MessageHandlingException` has a `failedMessage` property to get access to the original payload, which might be a file you have failed before.

Comment: Hello Artem, after this modification (sending exception  at the step '.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest()))  ), i 
I get the message on the errorChannel. But the problem is that it launches the other steps of the flow or that it should stop and not go to the next steps handle(jobLaunchingMessageHandler( )) and others ... Should I use router  and create other direct Channels ? or there is another way to keep the flow but stop it in case of receiving an error on ErrorChannel. thank you in advance

Comment: The error you got in the flow is really per message. Failing with message doesn't not justify a failure for another. I believe that's exactly what you see in your logs. You may stop a `fileReadingMessageSource` endpoint in the beginning of your flow to not poll for more files, but there is already nothing to do with messages on the fly.